# DevDays 2009 Reviews - Sitting at home crying

Tags: discussion, devdays, devdays-2009, videos

This is more of a collection question for all the content you could enjoy at home from the devdays.

So if you know of any videos then please post them here.

- [DevDays Intro Theme](http://vimeo.com/7094994)
- [Jon Skeet and Tony the Pony](http://vimeo.com/7403673) ([higher quality](http://vimeo.com/7516539))
- [DevDays Cambridge: Jeff Atwood](http://vimeo.com/7355062) (by [Perspx](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130027/perspx))

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because DevDays happened more than a decade ago and this question doesn't meet today's standards.

Answer (score 6):

#### Registration

Smooth and quick. The line was short and the atmosphere was pleasant. It wasn't much to gauge from the sign up booths what was in store for the rest of the day.

#### Venue

Way too busy. Too much in the way of tables and not nearly enough chairs. A disproportionate ratio that favoured standing room only. Only it really wasn't that much to write home about. Easy access to the flushing toilets was a boon though. And it would prove to be very handy after all the running back and forth from the free bottled tap water on hand.

#### Lunch

Selection of fruit was high on acidity; kiwifruit, pineapple, plums and oranges balanced only by the apples and bananas. Though you really couldn't eat more than one serving of each without wanting to try another fruit altogether. Variety was like you'd find in the fridge. Crisp though, it certainly had that going for it. At least you could taste the freshness in the bite.

#### Talks

Surprisingly slim. By far a disappointment. One highlight though was the presenter, (blanking on their name) who showed us all how to split a banana into three ways. Extremely enlightening.

#### Return?

For next year? Curiosity alone dictates a return to see if anything has improved or changed. Or if there will this time be speakers of note.

### Split a banana three ways

Managed to get the slide used for the thricewise divvy of a banana and some notes:

> 1. Peel your banana as you normally would
> 2. Bite off just a bit off the top to expose the veins of the banana central column. Looking down from the top you should see the gentle lines of three (3) divisions.
> 3. Work your finger down the hole at the centre of the banana carefully. It will part naturally and evenly into three sections.
>
> [image: split a nana]

Comment: @random - Okay. Gotta know how to split a banana three ways. That's an ancient, unsolvable problem in geometry. Do tell.

Comment: Well, as geometry problems go, I don't think the ancient Greeks would have considered that an acceptable "proof." But very cool, nonetheless.

Answer (score 4):

Stefan Plattner ([splattne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6461/splattne)) has a great compilation video from London with clips of talks by Joel, Jeff, Pekka Kosonen (Qt), Phil Nash (iPhone) and Jon Skeet.

It's hosted on both [Vimeo](http://vimeo.com/7381300) and [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8KdTGnL6-T4).