# Where can I watch or download all of the DevDay videos?

Tags: discussion, devdays, devdays-2009, videos

There are a lot of us who are unable to attend any of the DevDays because the locations are too far from where we reside. I was wondering whether there's a YouTube channel or a page where we can watch or download all of the DevDay videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: [DevDays 2009 Reviews - Sitting at home crying](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29004/devdays-reviews-sitting-at-home-crying)