# StackOverflow conference intro video. Where?

Tags: discussion, devdays, devdays-2009

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DevDays reviews - Sitting at home crying](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29004/devdays-reviews-sitting-at-home-crying)

Now, that's disappointing... I can't find the hilarious Spolsky/Atwood intro video from
DevDays. Not a presentable copy anyway.

I know this is off-topic, but this *is* StackOverflow ;)

Comment: Definitely meta.stackoverflow.com!

Comment: Shame on a 10k user tagging the original as "belongs-on-meta"!!!! boo hiss!

Comment: All DevDays content is here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29004/devdays-reviews-sitting-at-home-crying

Comment: @Ether - I didn't spot which user did it. They should know better.

Comment: @ChrisF: it was http://stackoverflow.com/users/17028/franci-penov in revision 2.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWHfY_lvKIQ

Comment: I don't think that's the one the author is referring to. Good video but that one is from a Google Tech Talk, not the DevDays video.